# Linq to xml Select statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to figure out how to do a select statement using linq to xml. I'd like to return the ServerTypes if the DeploymentType equals a specific value (Enterprise9999).

XML:

```
<Deployments>
  <Deployment>
    <DeploymentType>Enterprise9999</EnterpriseDeploymentType>
    <Servers>
      <DeploymentServer>
        <ServerType>WindowsServer</ServerType>
      </DeploymentServer>
      <DeploymentServer>
        <ServerType>LinuxServer</ServerType>
      </DeploymentServer>
    </Servers>
  </Deployment>
  <Deployment></Deployment>
  <Deployment></Deployment>
</Deployments>
```

Here's what I have so far in the code. I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@xmlFile);
IEnumerable<XElement> xlDeployments = from depRows in xmlDoc.Descendants("Deployments")
                                           select depRows;

var deploy = xlDeployments.Descendants("Deployment");

foreach (var dep in deploy)
{
    if (dep.Element("DeploymentType").ToString() == "Enterprise9999")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dep.Elements("ServerType").ToString());
    }
}
```

Is a namespace required for a select statement?

Comment: Your xml is not well formed

Comment: Specifically, this tag's closing tag doesn't match the opening tag:  
    <DeploymentType>Enterprise9999</EnterpriseDeploymentType>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed you're enclosing tag `</EnterpriseDeploymentType>` to `</DeploymentType>`

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@xmlFile);

var deployments = xmlDoc.Descendants("Deployment")
                       .Where(dep => dep.Element("DeploymentType") != null 
                                  && dep.Element("DeploymentType").Value == "Enterprise9999");

var servers = deployments.Descendants("ServerType")
                         .Select(node => node.Value);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, servers));
```

prints:

```
WindowsServer
LinuxServer
```

Comment: Good catch on the enclosing tag, I was trying to clean it up and missed it. This worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've corrected your XML as per my comment, you can use the following single query: -

```
var nodes = from n in xml.Descendants("DeploymentType")
                     .Where(x => x.Element("EnterpriseDeploymentType").Value.Equals("Enterprise9999"))
                        select n.Descendants("Servers").Descendants("ServerType").Select(s => s.Value);
```

Which will give you:

`WindowsServer`
`LinuxServer`

Comment: Thanks for the assist, I will play with the single line approach as well. :)